# Lua multithreading module

Tags: multithreading, lua, luajit

I'm looking for multithreading support for Lua/LuaJit.
I found http://lua-users.org/wiki/MultiTasking a lot of varians of modules, but I can't find up-to-date module.
Can somebody provide me the most useful Lua-threading? It is hardly difficult to find and choose.

Comment: I can point to my answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29370311/lua-threading/29414304#29414304. But really you should be more specific what you need from threads. May be you can just use async io. Do you need some sync and/or share data beetween threads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use [cqueues.thread](http://25thandclement.com/~william/projects/cqueues.html). It doesn't come with as much automatic serialisation/deserialisation as other solutions. But IMO it's a simpler model. Doesn't work on windows though.